# Javascript .toFixed(1) not rounding 0.05 properly

Tags: javascript

How can I round in javascript from 69.85 to 69.9. When I use .toFixed(1) it gives me 69.8 instead of 69.9.

Please refer below:

[image: Not rounding graph label]

Comment: Known issue with `toFixed`...
multiply by power of 10, round, divide back...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you further, could you please add some existing code to your question?

Comment: Voting to close as dupe

Comment: Maybe try [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), Also, if you're working with floating point numbers (which i believe is the default unless you typecast them), you'll want to round them before operating on them. [here's a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)